# delete row function

Tags: excel, vba

update: This is what i have so far, its supposed to search if an entry exists and if it has an in time, it throws an error 91 on line 3. i want the code to search for preexisting entries and update the time.

```
Sub inout()
        Dim barcode As String
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim rownumber As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        barcode = ws.Cells(2, 2).Value
    
        Set rng = ws.Columns("A").Find(What:=barcode, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not (rng Is Nothing) Or rng.Offset(0, 2) > 0 Then
            'checking out...
            Set rng = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            rng.Value = barcode
            rng.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            rng.Offset(0, 2).Clear
        ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then
            'checking out...
            Set rng = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            rng.Value = barcode
            rng.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Else
            'checking in...
            rng.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            rng.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
            rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
        End If
    
        ws.Cells(2, 2) = ""
    End Sub
```

[image: this is the layout of the page so far]

Comment: `rng.Offset(,1).Clear`?

Comment: perfect! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) - it will make your code more reliable

Without the Select/Activate:

```vb
Sub inout()
    Dim barcode As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rownumber As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    barcode = ws.Cells(2, 2).Value

    Set rng = ws.Columns("A").Find(What:=barcode, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        'checking out...
        Set rng = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        rng.Value = barcode
        rng.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
    Else
        'checking in...
        rng.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        rng.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
    End If
    
    ws.Cells(2, 2) = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: when i run the macro, nothing happens. :/

Comment: Did you try debugging?  Put a breakpoint on the `barcode = ...` line and step through the code using F8

Comment: alright, ive gotten to code to actually function now however, it only updates the "IN" column instead of out

Comment: Working example  - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzVEXC_ohNUVSjlD2sHQqoyd-AG81439/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks for the example tim! my only issue now is that once there is already an entry it wont update the out column. I believe ill need an elseif statement though im not too sure

Comment: i updated my question with the code i tried aswell